# Set class name inherit and display in another class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Why am I not able to set the class name and inherit it and display in another class like the code given below? What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class dealer
{
    string name;
public:
    dealer(){};
    dealer(string n): name(n){};
    ~dealer(){};
    //void setname(string n){name = n;};
    void display(){cout<<name<<endl;}
};
class car : public dealer
{
public:
    dealer b;
    car(){};
    //car(string n): dealer(n){};
    ~car(){};
    void display(){dealer::display();}
}; 
int main ()
{
    dealer a("ABC");
    car c;
    c.display();
}
```

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Comment: No error, its just not displaying the dealer name i.e. "ABC".

Comment: I guess you do want the car to display ABC? You then need to reread inheritance. You'll then know that the car's dealer instance is another instance than the dealer in your main function. Thus the ABC isn't set in the car's dealer instance hence you don't get the desired output.

Comment: a.display() should show you the dealear's name. c has nothing to do with the object a you created.

Comment: I understand, my question is. How do I make the relationship between the two classes for the second class to display the name of the dealer class.

Comment: Why design question, Why `a car is a dealer` as you use public inheritance here?

Comment: @billz I am sorry if I am asking the wrong questions. I am really new to c++, so I would like to know what would be the best way of inheriting this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is working properly. You initialize `c` with the `car` default constructor which implicitly call the `dealer` default constructor which doesn't do anything. `name` remains an empty string, which is what is printed out. To solve this problem:

```
//car(string n): dealer(n){}; <--- uncomment
car c("ABC"); //initialize like this
```

From comment: Your inheritance hierarchy is incorrect. `car` has-a `dealer`, but isn't a dealer. A better design system would look like this:

```
class dealer { ... };
class car
{
    dealer &d;
    car(dealer &nd): d(nd) { };
    void display(){ d.display();}
}
```

Comment: How do I resolve this? I don't want the name of the dealer to be set in the car class. I want to set the name of the dealer in the dealer class. If I set the name of the dealer in the car class it works, but not the other way round.

Comment: In this case, How can I use the step "dealer a("ABC");" in the main function?

Comment: `dealer a("ABC"); car c(a)`